# Query is working in sql developer but not in sql plus and it should throw an error

Tags: sql, oracle

[image]

```
select * 
from emp
where 
    (select salary from dual) in (select salary from employees);
```

`EMP` table has the same 107 which are in table `EMPLOYEES`. Here `select salary from dual` should produce an error in the where clause but it does not. How?

On the other hand it is returning rows in SQL Developer, but not in sqlplus. Why?

Comment: No,  it wont throw an error if  'select salary from dual' return only 1 row & column, and if the value returned exists in "select salary from employees" in will return all row in emp table. If the value does not exists, no row will be returned

Comment: But salary is not a valid identifier for the table dual, it will not return any row.

Comment: @AmanSinghRajpoot as pointed out in Littlefoot's answer, given the context, the `salary` in that subquery is a valid reference to `emp.salary`.  This is called a scalar subquery.  For each row in `emp`, the subquery will return the value of `salary` from that row.

Comment: It doesn't matter, let me rephrase your query to something like this ->                  select * from emp where '1000' in (select salary from employees);  This might make more sense for you

Comment: Yeah got it, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good! Hopefully, it'll teach you to use table **aliases**. Without them, it was a column from the `emp` table; as it exist, no error was thrown.

I don't have your tables so Scott's will do.

```
SQL> create table employees as select * From emp where deptno = 10;

Table created.

SQL> select a.*
  2  from emp a
  3  where
  4      (select a.sal from dual d) in (select b.sal from employees b);

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE        SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- -------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         7839 09.06.81       2450                    10
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT            17.11.81       5000                    10
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           7782 23.01.82       1300                    10

SQL> select a.*
  2  from emp a
  3  where
  4      (select d.sal from dual d) in (select b.sal from employees b);
    (select d.sal from dual d) in (select b.sal from employees b)
            *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00904: "D"."SAL": invalid identifier


SQL>
```

Comment: Yeah,  got it. Thank you very much. But why it did work in sql developer and not in sql plus.

Comment: You're welcome. For me, query works just the same in both environments. If you inserted data into some of those tables in SQL Developer, did you **commit**? If not, data wasn't visible in SQL*Plus.

Comment: I have truncated table and inserted new rows, my mistake. uncommitted data.

Comment: Right; it happens :)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a subquery when it is not necessary?  This should do what you want:

```
select e.*
from emp e
where e.salary in (select salary from employees);
```